# How can I add an array to an array of arrays using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have an array, as below:

```
var cString =   [
            ['1','Techdirt','www.techdirt.com'],
            ['2','Slashdot','slashdot.org'],
            ['3','Wired','wired.com']
            ];
```

to this array I want to add another in the same format:

```
var test = ['4','Stackoverflow','stackoverflow.com']
```

I've tried using:

```
var newArray = $.merge(cString, test);
```

But `console.log(newArray);` outputs:

```
[►Array,►Array,►Array,'4','Stackoverflow','stackoverflow.com']
```

So I'm *assuming* that I'm missing something obvious. Or attempting something stupid...help?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

jQuery is not needed for this. Just use [the Array's `.push()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) to add it to the main array.

```
var test = ['4','Stackoverflow','stackoverflow.com']

cString.push( test );
```

What `$.merge()` does is it walks through the second array you pass it and copies its items one by one into the first.

---

**EDIT:**

If you didn't want to modify the original array, you could make a copy of it first, and `.push()` the new Array into the copy.

```
var cString =   [
            ['1','Techdirt','www.techdirt.com'],
            ['2','Slashdot','slashdot.org'],
            ['3','Wired','wired.com']
            ];

var test = ['4','Stackoverflow','stackoverflow.com']

var newArray = cString.slice();

newArray.push( test );
```

Comment: Uhm, `console.log(newArray)` now returns `4` =/

Comment: @David - You sure about that? http://jsfiddle.net/XLVxw/1/ `4` would be the appropriate Array `length` property value.

Comment: @David - Oh, I see what you're doing. The `.push()` method modifies the original array, and returns the new length. That's why your `newArray` variable shows `4`.

Comment: yup I'm fairly certain =b And, seriously, thanks for the `forDummies()` jsfiddle demo. It was needed =) +1, and accepted!

Comment: @David - You're welcome! I should have paid more attention to the code in your question in the first place. :o)

Answer (score 2):

In addition to `push` as described by patrick, if you want to create a *new* list rather than changing the old, you can add arrays together with [`Array#concat`](http://docs.sun.com/source/816-6408-10/array.htm#1194827):

```
var newArray= cString.concat([['4','Stackoverflow','stackoverflow.com']]);
```

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but I think that would give OP the same result that `$.merge` was giving. I think you would need to do `cString.concat([['4','Stackoverflow','stackoverflow.com']])` instead.?

Answer (score 2):

you can use merge function like this

```
var newArray = $.merge($.merge([], cString), test);
```